# Some tag changes needed related to Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: support, tags

So [this](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-Certified-Kubernetes-and-Google-Kubernetes-Engine.html) has just happened, which necessitates some tag changes here.

Could someone with the appropriate permissions (I don't yet have enough rep to do so) kindly create tag [google-kubernetes-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine), and set [google-container-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) and [google-kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes) as synonyms thereof... or, better yet, could a moderator kindly merge the latter two into [google-kubernetes-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine) (even if it doesn't exist yet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged and synonymized [google-container-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) to [google-kubernetes-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine).

I've removed the synonym [google-kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes) from [kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes). As far as I can tell there's no particular need for this synonym anywhere, and having it in place is confusing. `Kubernetes` stands on its own, and entering `google-kubernetes` will now get you `google-kubernetes-engine` via autocompletion.

The existing questions under [kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) ought to be reviewed more thoroughly and retagged if necessary, though anyone in the community can edit or suggest such tag edits.